# How to save persistent data in Express?

Tags: express, session, cookies, storage

I have a simple requirement to store an access token/refresh token in Express (without using `localStorage` or anything). I'd like to store them in a persistent `httpOnly` cookie so any time a user visits the page who has previously visited the page can see if the access token is already there, and if so, make API calls and log in and so on.

I've spend some time looking at `express-session` and `cookie-session` and simply can't figure out the proper way to do it. `express-session` requires a store for production, and I don't want to set up a store to simply store an access token. So something like this works in devleopment:

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'conduit',
    cookie: {
      path: '/',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: isProduction,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
)
```

Using this to set it on request:

```
request.session.accessToken = accessToken
request.session.save()
```

But if it's not going to work in a production environment, it's not helpful. I haven't been able to get it working with `cookie-session`, or I don't know how to set/retrieve the cookies, and the documentation isn't very helpful.

So I'm asking: how can I store a few strings on an Express server/httpOnly cookie in a persistent way, without using a Store/Redis/MemCache/etc?

Answer (score 0):

I had to use cookieParser.

```js
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

app.use(cookieParser())

// set a cookie
response.cookie('nameOfCookie', 'cookieValue', {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 hour
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: isProduction,
})

// get a cookie
request.cookies.nameOfCookie

// destroy cookie
response.clearCookie('nameOfCookie')
```